# DetailView not opening from UITableViewController press (iOS Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Inside my TableView, I am pressing one of the cells to enter the detailed view, and for some reason it won't take me to the detailed view. Does anyone see a problem in the below code?

For context, this is a teacher directory, and pressing one of the cells brings up the teachers picture and other info.

Thanks for the help...if you need any more info I can add it in.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Get the selected teacher

NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Teachers"];
NSString *selectedTeacher = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedTeacher = selectedTeacher;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
dvController = nil;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if dvController is correctly loaded, so try to NSLog dvController once you have called the alloc-init. Another way to instantiate it is to use this simple call which works if you created the view controller and the xib together:

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Besides there is no reason to nil dvController at the end. If you're concerned with memory management, that is you don't want to leak dvController, simply autorelease it. So replace:

```
dvController=nil;
```

with:

```
[dvController autorelease];
```

this works because the navigation controller retains the pushed view controller
(or use ARC).

Finally I assume the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is called... if not sure, just a place a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I am using ARC so I deleted all of the release elements. I did create the nib and view controller together...Where would I add that line? Instead of the one with "initwithname"? Sorry for these basic questions...don't have much objective experience... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, try to add that line replacing yours. And remove the dvController=nil at the end. And immediately after the dvController =[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName...] add this line: NSLog(@"View controller: %@",dvController) and check in the debugger console that it prints something different than "null".

Comment: Ok thanks...still same problem...this is what is outputted '2012-02-05 14:49:47.751 App Name[6257:f803] View controller: <DetailViewController: 0x6e97f20>' any ideas? thanks for helping!

Comment: so the detail view controller is ok; I assume the navigation controller is in place too (try to add this: NSLog(@"Navigation controller: %@",self.navigationController);
Also, don't forget to remove the dvController=nil statement, it shouldn't impact but who knows...
In nothing works, it's impossible for me to help you further with just the code snapshot given.

Comment: I added in the NSLog for Navigation controller, and it did output "null."... Any other parts of the code I can throw up that would help?

Comment: This means you didn't load the navigation controller so you cannot push anything. This explains the issue. Probably the view controller that contains the table is not inside a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever resolved your problem, but I was having the same problem where my Detail View was not appearing. I finally replaced

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

with

```
[self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

and it worked. Hope that helps.

Comment: constique, thanks, that works for me too. But i don't see the back button present, it is something related to this issue ?, that means i am not able to go back to the first view ?